# Unable to access error logs of failed cromwell execution (WDL) in local machine running in ubuntu environment

Tags: errors, wdl

I was trying to run bases2fastq software downloaded from the element bioscience platform. I was running this software through WDL workflow named list_fastq. For some reason, maybe syntax, my cromwell execution failed. However, I haven't been able to read the logs as they are empty. Below is the content of the 'stderr.background' file.

```
mkfifo: cannot create fifo '/mnt/d/element-bioscience/cromwell-executions/list_fastq/5e9a780d-c010-41f7-bba0-bcb42c870891/call-list_samples/tmp.05c20794/out.78994': Operation not supported
mkfifo: cannot create fifo '/mnt/d/element-bioscience/cromwell-executions/list_fastq/5e9a780d-c010-41f7-bba0-bcb42c870891/call-list_samples/tmp.05c20794/err.78994': Operation not supported
/mnt/d/element-bioscience/cromwell-executions/list_fastq/5e9a780d-c010-41f7-bba0-bcb42c870891/call-list_samples/execution/script: line 17: /mnt/d/element-bioscience/cromwell-executions/list_fastq/5e9a780d-c010-41f7-bba0-bcb42c870891/call-list_samples/tmp.05c20794/out.78994: No such file or directory
/mnt/d/element-bioscience/cromwell-executions/list_fastq/5e9a780d-c010-41f7-bba0-bcb42c870891/call-list_samples/execution/script: line 18: /mnt/d/element-bioscience/cromwell-executions/list_fastq/5e9a780d-c010-41f7-bba0-bcb42c870891/call-list_samples/tmp.05c20794/err.78994: No such file or directory
```

Please guide me to the steps on being able to prevent cromwell from deleting the contents of log files, if that's what's happening.